# what is the limit of this special linear function?

Tags: calculus

Let's say we have a function where $y = 2 x + 3$, but for $x = 2$, the $y$ is not $7$, but $5$. What is the limit of the function for $x$ tends to $2$? Is it $5$? Is it 7? Is it something else?

Comment: Cool down! You might want to edit this question into a less angry tone, unless you want to attract downvotes. From what you write, it looks like you had the same question closed earlier, and in that case it's probably because people felt that you didn't provide enough context. How did this question arise? What are your own thoughts? (Too many people just post their homework questions verbatim on this site, and that's why many users here are a bit "allergic" to questions that don't show any signs of effort from the person asking.)

Comment: this question rised to me as I read the textbook 'calculus for dummies'. It is not a homework question. And I don't know why the system didn't let me post it!

Comment: Neither do I. Anyway, it's a perfectly valid question to ask, and it also shows the importance of having a precise definition to fall back upon in cases where one's intuition is insufficient. (I have no idea if your book gives the precise definition, but judging from its title, I suspect that it doesn't...) You can read it [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit), for example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what definition of limit you're using. Most (but not all) sources give a definition where the value of the function at the point that $x$ tends to (if $f$ has a value there) should *not* be taken into account when computing the limit. The limit is "the value that the *surrounding* points think that the function ought to have at that point". So in your case, the limit is $7$. (The fact that $f$ "disobeys" and takes the value $5$ instead means that $f$ is discontinuous at the point $x=2$.)